# Universal Windows - await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync() don't seem to await file to get written

Tags: c#, uwp

I am trying something that should be straightforward, saving and then loading a file in UWP. (Universal Windows Platform) However, it is not *always* working.

Functions:

```
public async Task<bool> WriteFile(string fileName, byte[] byteArray){
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, byteArray);
        return true;
}

public async Task<IBuffer> ReadFile(string fileName){
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);

        IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);

        return buffer;
}
```

Calling code:

```
byte[] fancyByteArray = { 0,1,2,3,4,5 };
Task<bool> t = WriteFile("Testfile", fancyByteArray);
Task<byte[]> task = ReadFile("Testfile");
IBuffer res = task.Result;
```

Well, this works sometimes. And that is the problem, because sometimes it does not work! Sometimes the file seem to be created or recreated, but no content. (Size on disk are zero bytes) Sometimes I get a file-does-not-exist error.

It is not a big file, 64 bytes, so it cannot be something related to "big file still being written" to disk.

I assume "await" means "wait until those darn bytes are written to disk", but maybe I get this wrong?! Maybe I should somehow check that the thing actually is finished writing to disk?

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017, latest everything as far as I know. Applications target version are set to "Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)".

Comment: You need change your code format !

Comment: @lindexi, please give an example.

Comment: You need see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/02/09/automatic-code-formatter-released-to-github/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `await` is inside the method but your actual calls are not awaited. So before the writing is completed, it will try to read the content of the file.

Instead await your `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` like below.

```
byte[] fancyByteArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };  
bool t = await WriteFile("Testfile", fancyByteArray);  
byte[] task = await ReadFile("Testfile");
```

And your `WriteFile` and `ReadFile` should be like below

```
public async Task<bool> WriteFile(string fileName, byte[] byteArray)  
{  
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;  
    StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);  
    await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, byteArray);  
    return true;  
}  

public async Task<byte[]> ReadFile(string fileName)  
{  
    StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;  
    StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);  
    IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(file);  
    return buffer.ToArray();  
}
```

Update:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] fancyByteArray = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    bool t = await WriteFile("Testfile", fancyByteArray);
    byte[] task = await ReadFile("Testfile");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I call ReadFile and WriteFile straight from the constructor AppData::AppData(), so I cannot use 'await' there. The compiler stops me with this message: "The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'." ...I really have a problem understanding how to use this..

Comment: @Snorvarg Instead of Constructor, Use this in Overridable `OnNavigatedTo` method and then make that async. See Updated Answer.

Comment: that would work, thanks. But I must have another problem, because now I tested stop calling the WriteFile() alltogether, and just call ReadFile(). (File is on disk already) But now it stop at StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName); in ReadFile() and never stop awaiting it... Any clues? (File is on disk, was written in an earlier run of the program, has the expected 48 bytes.)

Comment: It is as expected. await calls will wait for any operation to be completed before moving to next one, So is the reason why it waits for the file to be read and then return the content.

Comment: If you do not want your navigation to hang and load the page first and then call these functions, Instead of `OnNavigatedTo`, Use `YourPage_Loaded`.

Comment: I made a test-project with just the code you propose, and it works. So my bigger and more messy project I have been fiddling with must have some other bugs as well. I mark your answer as the correct one, thank's a lot!

Comment: I found this article somewhere else on stackoverflow: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html
It's a great article, and finally I wrapped my head around it!